# Get the names of the files created in a particular month and then zip them separately

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder that have multiple subfolders and files. They contains almost a million files. I need to create zip files for each month, so that they are easy to move. For example, I want to zip all files created in Jan 2021 in Jan_2021.zip, and zip all files created in Feb 2021 in Feb_2021.zip

My problem is that when I get timestamp with ctime, its not something that I can filter. Can anyone help me understand how can I get names of files created in a particular month.

```
import os,time

src1 = "C:\\Users\\My-Info"
os.chdir(src1)

for file in os.listdir():
print(file + "Time Stamp - " + str(time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))))
```

It gives me output like this:

```
Payslip - Tue Dec 21 12:57:07 2021
Process - Thu Feb 17 20:46:23 2022
Scripts - Tue Dec 21 12:57:07 2021
```

I am on windows with python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list containing the name of the file and its creation date (month-year). Then you join in a list the files having the same date.

```
import os
import datetime

data = [[datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file)).strftime("%b-%Y"), file] for file in os.listdir()]

final_data = {}
for file in data:
    if file[0] in final_data:
        final_data[file[0]].append(file[1])
    else:
        final_data[file[0]] = [file[1]]
print(final_data)
```

**Output**:

```
{'Dec-2021': ['Payslip', 'Scripts'], 'Feb-2022': ['Process']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `groupby()` the files on the creation year+month:

```
import itertools

def get_ctime(file):
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file)).strftime("%Y%m")

files = sorted(os.listdir(), key=get_ctime)
for yyyymm, files in itertools.groupby(files, key=get_ctime):
    print("Files created in ", yyyymm)
    for f in files:
        print(file, time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file)))
    print("")
```

The `get_ctime()` function takes a file, gets its `ctime` and formats it as `YYYYMM`. `groupby()` groups consecutive files of the same value from this function together, which is why we need to sort `files` by the same `key` before running `groupby()` on it.